# Disabling Android Device Manager location notification on Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, geolocation, notification-icons

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4. When you use the Android Device Manager to locate your phone it shows a notification that it was utilized, which is stupid in my opinion as it tells the bad guys/gals what you are doing.

I went to Settings, Application Manager and All and tried to locate the "Android Device manager and Device Manager" to disable it as was indicated by another responder, however I did not see either to be listed.

I would like very much to know how to disable this notification.

Answer (score 2):

The "location accessed" notification comes from **Google Play Services**. (You can find out what app a notification comes from by long-pressing it and then selecting "app info.")

To disable notifications from **Google Play Services**, open Settings > Apps > All > Google Play Services, and then untick *show notifications*, then accept the prompt.

*Note: After disabling these notifications, you may not receive certain alerts from that app, like updating Google Play services.*

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's site](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?hl=en)

- From your device's apps menu, open Google Settings .
- Touch Security.
- Under "Android Device Manager," move the switches next to "Remotely locate this device" and "Allow remote lock and factory reset" to the on or off position. Make sure you sign into your Google account on your device if you want to use Android Device Manager.

Make sure you're going to "Google Settings", not just the normal "Settings" menu.